# Add scrollbar to bootstrap modal body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add scrollbar to bootstrap modal body. But it add to entire content.How to add it to only to body.was using modals which had long content, and the modals automatically scrolled when a given max height was reached.

This is my code

```
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link href="/<s:text name="app.name"/>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

.modal-body {
max-height: calc(100vh - 212px);
overflow-y: auto;
}
</head>


<body>
<div>
<s:if test="user.level == 0 && name != ''">
<button id="roleBtn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick=""
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleModal">
<s:text name="roles"/>
</button>
</s:if>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="roleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:80%;  margin-top: 60px; margin-bottom:30px;">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><s:text name="headingRoles"/></h4>
</div>

<s:form theme="simple" method="post" action="UserSupport">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
<s:hidden name="docType" value="userLevel"/>
<div>
<s:hidden name="name"/>
<s:iterator value="userRoles" status="rowstatus">
<s:hidden name="userRoles[%{#rowstatus.index}].role" value="%{role}"/>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>

<div class="col-xs-8" align="left">
<div class="checkbox">
<label></label><s:checkbox name="userRoles[%{#rowstatus.index}].selected"
value="name != ''"/> <s:property
value="roleName"/></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</s:iterator>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="panel-body" align="center">
<s:submit method="saveRoles" cssClass="btn btn-primary"
value="%{getText('save')}"></s:submit>
<button type="button" method="resetRoles" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
<s:text name="close"/>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</s:form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

it doesn't work as expected. The modal window does reach a maximum size, but it just cuts its content there and the footer is not even displayed.Answers are welcome

Thank you

Comment: it would be easier for other people to check/play with your code if you prepare a fiddle for it.

Comment: see this:https://www.bootply.com/T0yF2ZNTUd

Answer (score 5):

Just provide overflow hidden to the .modal class and provide overflow scroll to the modal body...

```
.modal .modal-content{
overflow:hidden;
}
.modal-body{
overflow-y:scroll; // to get scrollbar only for y axis
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body,html{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
.modal-dialog{
        height:calc(100% - 60px);
}
.modal-content{
  height:100%;
 }
.modal-header{
        height:50px;

}
.model-footer{
        height:75px;
}
.modal-body {
height:calc(100% - 125px);
overflow-y: scroll;     /*give auto it will take based in content */
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div>
<s:if test="user.level == 0 && name != ''">
<button id="roleBtn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick=""
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleModal">Open model
<s:text name="roles"/>
</button>
</s:if>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="roleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><s:text name="headingRoles"/></h4>
</div>

<s:form theme="simple" method="post" action="UserSupport">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
<s:hidden name="docType" value="userLevel"/>
<div>
<s:hidden name="name"/>
<s:iterator value="userRoles" status="rowstatus">
<s:hidden name="userRoles[%{#rowstatus.index}].role" value="%{role}"/>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>

<div class="col-xs-8" align="left">
<div class="checkbox">
<label></label><s:checkbox name="userRoles[%{#rowstatus.index}].selected"
value="name != ''"/> <s:property
value="roleName"/></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</s:iterator>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="panel-body" align="center">
<s:submit method="saveRoles" cssClass="btn btn-primary"
value="%{getText('save')}"></s:submit>
<button type="button" method="resetRoles" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
<s:text name="close"/>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</s:form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#exampleModalLongTitle

```
<!-- Scrollable modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap, dont add some CSS, just use class "overflow-hidden" on the div with modal-content class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).